# Is there a way to utilise CSS3 animations/@keyframes in a MailChimp template

Tags: css, animation, mailchimp

Inspired by [this HTML newsletter,](http://designjunction.createsend4.com/t/ViewEmail/i/0C8E0580D2D7CBE8/3B807FACCAFA01B32540EF23F30FEDED) I decided to incorporate some keyframes animations in a MailChimp template. The animation itself works great locally, but when it's uploaded to MailChimp the `@keyframe` rules and the `%` are stripped out. It goes from this...

```
@keyframes fadein {
    0% { opacity:0 }
    100% { opacity:1 }
}
```

... to this ...

```
0 { opacity: 0 }
100 { opacity:1 }
```

It looks like MailChimp isn't parsing it and stripping elements out. I haven't had much luck searching MailChimp support for any info regarding this. Has anyone found a clever way of working around this?

Comment: MailChimp has a list of CSS selectors that are supported in email clients found here in their **Email Template Reference**: http://templates.mailchimp.com/resources/email-client-css-support - also client specific styles: http://templates.mailchimp.com/development/css/client-specific-styles -

Comment: @jonathan Technically my issue isn't/wasn't to do with CSS selectors but those are useful resources for the future, so thanks for those!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just had it confirmed by MailChimp support; they currently don't support that degree of customisation and any unsupported code is automatically stripped out by their editor. Shame.

Comment: I can also confirm that this doesn't work either in the campaign editor WYSIWYG or in the template creator.

Comment: Thanks for confirming that @max_w. Guess I'll have to drop that feature until the y add support for it (if they ever do). It's not the biggest loss; support for CSS3 animations in mail clients is pretty low at the moment anyway.

Answer (score 2):

You can use CSS3 animations with Mailchimp by putting the required CSS in an external CSS file e.g.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://example.com/email/style.css">
```

I've successfully done this with a number of email campaigns and they look good on iPhone, iPad and Macs.

Answer (score 1):

**MailChimp** states that CSS should be **inline** or might be at risk of being stripped out:

http://kb.mailchimp.com/article/the-css-in-my-campaign-is-not-working-or-is-getting-stripped/

> Don't place CSS inside the HEAD tags in HTML Email.
>
> When you code a web page, you traditionally place the CSS code in between the HEAD tags, above your content. But when HTML emails are viewed in browser-based email apps (like YahooMail!, Gmail, Hotmail, etc), those applications strip out the HEAD and BODY tags by default.
>
> We recommend you place your CSS code inline to your content (note: browser-based email apps also strip out your BODY tag, so any background colors or BODY settings should be handled with a 100% wide TABLE "wrapper" around your email).

They have a Automatic CSS-inliner feature:

http://www.mailchimp.com/kb/article/how-does-the-css-inliner-work

MailChimp has a list of CSS selectors that are supported in email clients found here:

http://templates.mailchimp.com/resources/email-client-css-support

also client specific styles:

http://templates.mailchimp.com/development/css/client-specific-styles

Comment: While I would *love* to mark your answer as the right answer, it doesn't actually solve my problem. MailChimp (currently) does not support `@keyframe` animations, whether inline or not. +1 for providing useful links though.

Comment: @Dre no worries just sharing those links from MailChimp, as i was having a similar issue with them also